# Nested resource redirect to new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ryan's Railscast #154 he discusses polymorphic associations.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

Here the new comments form is displayed as part of the show action for the parent item such as articles.

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @commentable = @article
  @comments = @commentable.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

When the form is submitted the comments => new action processes the request.

```
def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This works well however when the comment record cannot be saved the controller 'new' view of the comments controller.

```
else
  render :new
```

This takes the user to the comments new form. It would be better for the controller rendered the 'show" action of the parent controller, Articles or otherwise.

I am interested to know how to render a view from the @commentable item. I have tried the following without success.

```
else
  render [:new, @commentable]
```

Comment: Calling render will render that template with the instance vars you've set in your action (`create`). You can just `render :show` provided you've set the instance variables you need in your template. 

Also, unrelated to your question, but in your show, you can set `@commentable = Article.find(params[:id])` -- and reference `@commentable` wherever you've set `@article` -- saves a little bit of memory.

Comment: Hi Mike and thanks. Calling :show will attempt to render a comments/show template. In the create action of the comments controller I need to render /articles/show template or better still render the /commentable/show action